# How long is 5 minutes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, diablo-3

This morning I answered [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/68511/4775) with [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68513/4775).  The question's timestamp is 14:17:36Z, and my answer's is 14:22:20Z.  Unless I'm bad at math, this is within 5 minutes, and should earn the Perfect Topaz gem, but I haven't been awarded it.

Unless "answer a question within 5 minutes of it being asked" also requires being the accepted answer, in which case the description should be clarified.

**Edit**

I just answered another question and was immediately given the gem for it.  As a result, I'm assuming that the problem is actually a bug with whatever's checking the time.  I've changed the tags accordingly

Comment: You must wait 15 minutes from the question timestamp before you can accept an answer so I'd say that's not it

Comment: @badp I was implying more along the lines of "answered within 5 minutes and that answer was accepted," not that it was was accepted within 5 minutes.  I'm not sure if that's actually a requirement, though

Comment: Pretty sure it also needs to be upvoted. Beyond that, there has historically been some delay in contest criteria like this updating to the profile.

Comment: Was totally going to troll and answer 5 minutes. But to hell with it.

Comment: Woops, we were mis-using [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) ..a fix'll go out shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We weren't correctly awarding the Perfect Topaz in some near-5-minute cases, due to a bug in the SQL query. It's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks @Emmett!